# Can I list all standard Go packages?

Tags: go, go-packages

Is there a way in Go to list *all* the standard/built-in packages (i.e., the packages which come installed with a Go installation)?

I have a list of packages and I want to figure out which packages are standard.

Comment: Default `Go` packages https://golang.org/pkg/

Comment: Is there a  function like `isStandardPackage(importPath string) bool` which i can use?

Comment: can this be used? https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/list/ ?

Comment: I think list to show you all install packages.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? An import statement without a `.` is either an internal package of your own or a part of the standard library.

Comment: We were trying to organize code in kubernetes. We need a easy way to figure out in one of the scripts if this a standard package and can be ignored for analysis.

Answer (score 57):

You can use the new [`golang.org/x/tools/go/packages`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages) for this. This provides a programmatic interface for most of `go list`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(nil, "std")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(pkgs)
    // Output: [archive/tar archive/zip bufio bytes compress/bzip2 ... ]
}
```

To get a `isStandardPackage()` you can store it in a map, like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

var standardPackages = make(map[string]struct{})

func init() {
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(nil, "std")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, p := range pkgs {
        standardPackages[p.PkgPath] = struct{}{}
    }
}

func isStandardPackage(pkg string) bool {
    _, ok := standardPackages[pkg]
    return ok
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isStandardPackage("fmt"))  // true
    fmt.Println(isStandardPackage("nope")) // false
}
```

Comment: Immediately searched where does `ok` come from and found this nice article.
https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/35d0b2/about_the_comma_ok_idiom/

Comment: The `packages.Load(nil, "std")` call executes the `go list` command and parses the output.  I note this for others who might also make the incorrect assumption that the package provides the command implementation.

Answer (score 40):

Use the `go list std` command to list the standard packages.  The special import path `std` expands to all packages in the standard Go library ([doc](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns)).

Exec that command to get the list in a Go program:

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "list", "std")
p, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
stdPkgs = strings.Fields(string(p))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple solution, you could check if a package is present in $GOROOT/pkg. All standard packages are installed here.