# How to list all non-standard/custom packages in Go?

Tags: go, go-packages

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807322/can-i-list-all-standard-go-packages/56199212) one can get all the standard Go packages using https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages 's `Load()` function in which one can give "pattern" as input.

`pkgs, err := packages.Load(nil, pattern)`

For example, if `pattern = "std"` then it returns all the standard packages.

But, if I want to get a list of custom/user-defined packages having custom patterns such as only the vendor folders of the form `github.com/X/Y/vendor/...` then how exactly I can specify the pattern?

I have tried using `/vendor/`, `github.com/X/Y/vendor/` and some other combinations as `pattern` in the `Load()` function. None of them have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `...` syntax in `pattern` field of the `Load()` function.

#### Example

My Go module requires [`github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror`](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror) package :

```
module mymodule

require github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror v1.0.0
```

So, the following code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(nil, "github.com/hashicorp...")
    if err == nil {
        for _, pkg := range pkgs {
            fmt.Println(pkg.ID)
        }
    }
}
```

returns all the required packages starting with `github.com/hashicorp` (even transitive ones) :

```
github.com/hashicorp/errwrap
github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror
```

Note that you can also use `...` anywhere in your pattern (`...hashicorp...`, `...ha...corp...`, `github.com/...`).

Comment: Thanks @norbjd! It turned out I had tried all combinations except the `...` ones which I mentioned in the question itself. :| 
BTW when I use `...vendor...` I don't get expected results. But I do get expected results for all other combinations like `...X...`. Is it the case for you as well? What's so special about `vendor`?

Comment: If you are talking about `vendor` directory (generated by `go mod vendor`), it is not a package itself, it is just a directory with a local copy of all your external dependencies.